# Resize canvas size as window is being resized (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

## What I want to do

I want to keep the canvas size full to the window.

---

## What the problem is

I set the canvas size as stated below.

```js
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

[image: The canvas size seems full]

It worked.

---

But when I resized the window, the canvas size didn't change but instead kept its initial size.

[image: The canvas size doesn't change]

**What should I do to keep the canvas size full to the window without changing the balls' size?**

---

## Here is my code

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#sandBox');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, r, c) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.c = c;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

const balls = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 15;
  let x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - r * 2) + r;
  let y = Math.random() * (canvas.height - r * 2) + r;
  let c = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
  balls.push(new Circle(x, y, r, c));
}

balls.forEach(ball => ball.draw());
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  /* width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh; */
  background-color: #393939;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="sandBox"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a callback `onresize` and use that to recreate the canvas:

Each time you resize the window you'll have to redraw the canvas, unless you save it somewhere.

```js
function init() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#sandBox");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, r, c) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.r = r;
      this.c = c;
    }

    draw() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
  }

  const balls = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 15;
    let x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - r * 2) + r;
    let y = Math.random() * (canvas.height - r * 2) + r;
    let c = "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)";
    balls.push(new Circle(x, y, r, c));
  }

  balls.forEach((ball) => ball.draw());
}

window.onload = function() {
  init();
};
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #393939;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body onresize="init()">
  <canvas id="sandBox"></canvas>
</body>
```